# why goland+vim+visual select it to delete it

Tags: goland, ideavim

I use Goland to write GO programs, and use the VIm plug-in, I find that when in Visual mode, any extension causes deletion. For example, when I press V and then E, I want to check to the end of the word, but actually delete to the end of the word.
I used ideavimrc to configure the VIM mod, here is my config

```
set mouse=
" 显示当前模式
set shownmode
" 共享系统粘贴板
set clipborad=unamed
" 打开行号
set number
" 打开相对行号
set relativenumber
" 关闭兼容vi
set nocompatible
" 开启语法高亮功能
syntax enable
" 允许用指定语法高亮配色方案替换默认方案
syntax on
" 模式搜索实时预览,增量搜索
set incsearch
" 设置搜索高亮
set hlsearch
" vim自身命令行模式智能补全
set wildmenu
" 总是显示状态栏
set laststatus=2
" 显示光标当前位置
set ruler
" 展示命令
set showcmd
" 高亮显示当前行/列
set cursorline
"set cursorcolumn
" 禁止折行
set nowrap
" 将制表符扩展为空格
set expandtab
" 设置编辑时制表符占用空格数
set tabstop=4
" 设置格式化时制表符占用空格数
set shiftwidth=4
" 让 vim 把连续数量的空格视为一个制表符
set softtabstop=4
" 基于缩进或语法进行代码折叠
set foldmethod=indent
set foldmethod=syntax
" 启动 vim 时关闭折叠代码
set nofoldenable
" leader键
let mapleader = " "

map <esc><esc> :w<CR>

" 当光标一段时间保持不动了，就禁用高亮，ideavim不起作用？
autocmd cursorhold * set nohlsearch
noremap <Leader>n :set nohlsearch<cr>
" 当输入查找命令时，再启用高亮
noremap n :set hlsearch<cr>n
noremap N :set hlsearch<cr>N
noremap / :set hlsearch<cr>/
noremap ? :set hlsearch<cr>?
noremap * *:set hlsearch<cr>

" 插入模式下移动光标
inoremap <C-b> <Left>
inoremap <C-f> <Right>
inoremap <C-a> <Left>^i
inoremap <C-e> <Esc>$a


" 定义快捷键到行首行尾
noremap <Leader>a ^
noremap <Leader>e $

" 中英文自动切换
set keep-english-in-normal-and-restore-in-insert

" easymotion
set easymotion
map <Leader>l <Plug>(easymotion-lineforward)
map <Leader>j <Plug>(easymotion-j)
map <Leader>k <Plug>(easymotion-k)
map <Leader>h <Plug>(easymotion-linebackward)

set ideajoin
```